# Find the largest rectangular grid pattern from a set of 2D points

Tags: algorithm, points

I have been struggling with the 2D version of finding [Longest Arithmetic Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-arithmetic-subsequence/) .

Given a set of 2D points in **integers**, is there an efficient algorithm that finds the **largest subset** of these points that form a NxM **rectangular** grid (e.g. 7x3, 4x4, 1x3, 2x1, 1x1) pattern, where the grid size is calculated as NxM? Note that the grid pattern can have different step sizes along X and Y directions. Also, single row (1xM), single column (Nx1) and single element (1x1) are also considered special rectangular grid patterns.

For points in the figure, the algorithm should return the 3x3 rectangular grid pattern of size 9 in red

[image: 2]

All suggestions and references are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Need some more info. Does NxM grids allowed, for example 7x3 grid? How do you calculate size of grid? Which size have a line, like (point)line(point)line(point)line(point)? Are coordinates integer?

Comment: First idea: you can group points by X coordinate and delete, points, that is alone in their groups (There is no pair for making any rectangle). Then you can group remaining point by Y coordinate and reduce points amount again. Then again with X... until you can delete point. I think it can significant reduce point's amount, if points are random.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have edited the question based on my understanding, although I don't quite follow "Which size have a line, like (point)line(point)line(point)line(point)?"

Comment: BTW,  single row (1xM), single column (Nx1) and single element (1x1) are also considered special rectangular grid patterns.

Answer (score 1):

`O(n^4)` - (fits only for tiny points sets) solution:
You can use this [idea](https://massivealgorithms.blogspot.com/2019/04/leetcode-1027-longest-arithmetic.html) of trying all point pairs as difference of minimal element. For pair (x1, y1), (x2, y2) you should build largest rectangular grid with top left corner in (x1, y1) with small rectangle `width = (x2 - x1)` and `height = (y2 - y1)`. There is `O(n^2)` pairs.

To build largest rectangular grid you can for every possible (1xK) horisontal line with top left corner in (x1, y1) try to expand it down as long as possible. In worst case it's `O(n^2)` too. But it will be not so bad, if there is no long lines in the points set. I think here lies some optimization hints if solution will be too long, because in this algorithm you check each cell many times.

if single rows and columns have non zero size, so you cannot use advice about deleting points, which hasn't vertical or horisontal pair.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this idea (and the nice blog archive of algorithms).